# Why is ^\d+$ matching a string that is fully numeric?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

The following regex

```
moo = re.compile(r'^\d+$')
```

would search for a string that just starts and ends with a numeric character. Examples can be `11234`, `44332`, `123321321`, etc.

But the regex does not match `12321xyz12312` . This string also starts and ends with a number and that is all my regex needs to match a string ! Then why isn't my regex matching this string too?

Comment: "The regex `moo=re.compile(r'^\d+$')` would search for a string that just starts and ends with a numeric character." - nope. If you explain why you thought that, we can explain your misunderstanding.

Comment: If you want to match a string that just starts and ends with a digit, with whatever you don't care about in the middle, you use `re.compile(r'^\d.*\d$')`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: Except that that doesn't match a single-digit string like `'1'`, so if you want to match those (you probably do), you'd need to special-case it or use lookaround assertions or just not use regexes or something.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks. `r'^(?:\d.*\d)|\d$'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you misunderstood how the start and end matchers work.

`^\d+$` does not simply match a string that ends and starts with a number. It's saying that:

- go to the start of the string (`^`)
- match a number (`\d`)
- match as many of those numbers as possible (`+`)
- now continue to try matching these until the end of the string (`$`)

`12321xyz12312` does not match because after it matches `12321`, it tries to match the end of the string. But it isn't at the end yet, so the string does not match!

Here is a regex that does what you want:

```
^\d(.*\d)?$
```

That expression will match the following:

```
YES  0 
 NO  x0
 NO  0x
YES  00
YES  000
YES  0x0
YES  00x00
YES  000xxx000
```

Comment: Could you please give me a regex that that will match a string that has numeric digits at both ends no matter which characters does it have inside it?

Comment: @M.Hamel Did you see my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45517557/why-is-d-matching-a-string-that-is-fully-numeric?noredirect=1#comment77996423_45517557)

Comment: I've updated the regex. The one before would have not required numerical digits on the end correctly.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thanks!

Comment: @Soviut You should probably write your own answer instead of editing this user's to this degree...

Comment: Also as Twickler said, this regex won't match single digit strings like `1`.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ the regex I provided matches `1` though. Is that not what the OP wanted?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ , Is this Okay too? `^\d+(\w+)\d+$`

Comment: @M.Hamel No it isn't, because you're expecting strings to be there. If there are no strings, it fails.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ No, I mean the one I gave in revision 3. `^\d(.*\d)?$`. Should I change it back?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I was cleaning up the best answer rather than duplicating work.

Answer (score 1):

`"^\d+$"` means "one or more decimal digits `"\d+"` between the start `"^"` and the end `"$"`." `xyz` are not decimal digits.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're misunderstanding the regex. It matches "beginning of string" (`^`) immediately followed by "one or more 0-9 characters" (`\d+` -- `\d` is the same as `[0-9]` or `0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9` and `+` means "repeated one or more times") immediately followed by "end of string" (`$`).

That is, `^ ... $` means "only match strings that are exactly whatever the `...` is" (as opposed to "match strings that contain it somewhere").